# Calling a substitution function Regex Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm using the following code to call a replace function whenever the regex expression matches in the string myString. My question is whether I can call a different replace function based on whether the regex matches with a `${STRING}` or a `$STRING`

```
def replace(match):
    match = match.group()

    if matched == ${STRING}
        return os.getenv(match[1:],'') 
    elif matched == $STRING:
        return something else
    else:
        return error

def main()
    myString = "my string ${withcool} $stuff"
    re.sub("\$.+|\$\{.+\}",replace,myString)
```

Comment: You'll need a function or at least a short lambda expression to decide which function to call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to extract the **variable** and evaluate it.

If so, you don't need to call different functions to extract the variable, you can just use parentheses(capturing group) to extract it.

Like:

```
def replace(match):
    print match.groups()
s='my string ${withcool} ${withcool2} $stuff'
re.sub(r'\$\{(\w+)\}', replace, s)
```

It will gives:

```
('withcool',)
('withcool2',)
```

As you see, the **variable** is extracted already.

But if you want to match two or more patterns, it'll be a bit complex.

If you use `re.sub(r'\$(\w+)|\$\{(\w+)\}', replace, s)`, `match.groups()` will be:

```
(None, 'withcool')
(None, 'withcool2')
('stuff', None)
```

You need to get the element which is not `None` from the tuple.

BTW, I suggest that using `\w` instead of `.` as you are using greedy regex.